# Can va_lists in stdarg.h handle C++ references?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, variadic-functions, variadic

Can `va_list`s handle C++ references? I know they can handle ints, doubles and pointers, but not floats, chars, etc. Can they handle C++ references?

Comment: not floats, chars etc? Can you provide a reference for that? I don't know `va_list` and I am quite surprised by what you say. I checked quickly but didnt not find anything like that

Comment: I guess they mean the fact that when an expression of type `float` is given as an argument to a variadic function, it's converted to `double`, and so the called function has to retrieve it with `va_arg(ap, double)`.  `va_arg(ap, float)` typically won't work.  Likewise `char` is converted to `int` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-ak715zIIE

Comment: @NateEldredge so would references be ok?

Comment: the video is about variadic functions in C. Your question is about C++. Also the C++ header is `cstadarg` not `stdarg.h`. Don't confuse C and C++ to be the same just because C++ tries to be similar

Comment: @Serket Youtube videos are never an answer to anything programming. Please provide a link to the documentation, or a quote from the standard, that states this, instead.

Comment: va_list is for C code. In C++ we use templates, which are superior to prehistoric C variadic parameters in every possible way. You will not learn C++ from some random Youtube video, but only from a good C++ textbook that will explain to you what templates are and how to use them.

Comment: I wouldnt go as far as to *demand* a better reference, but yes a youtube video (about a different language) is a quite low bar to say "I know" ;)

Comment: When you are using C++ you should take a look at [variadic templates/parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). That might be a better alternative.

Comment: @churill do I have to use variadic templates? I find them very odd to use. Will I be fine using the C method, or will it cause problems down the line?

Comment: using `va_args` in C++ is very very odd. I tried to wrap my head around once without much sucess. Variadic templates on the other hand takes a single example to get the basic idea and it is really simple. Variadic templates are type safe by their very defintion, `va_args` i dont know how to achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `#include <cstdarg>` rather than `<stdarg.h>`...

If the caller provides a reference as an argument to such a function, the call will work the same way as if the referenced object was specified directly.  For example, if you have:

```
void f(...);
T my_t;
T& x = my_t;
f(my_t);
f(x);
```

The values passed in registers and/or on the stack as arguments for `f` will be the same in both calls (assuming out-of line calls, and functionally equivalent if inlined).

So, "can they handle C++ references" - yes, in the way described above, which may or may not be what you wanted/expected.

---

Just a word of caution: if you have...

```
f(A& b, ...);
```

...the behaviour is undefined, as the `va_start` macro doesn't support having the final pre-`...`-matching argument be a reference (you can't pass a lambda capture nor pack expansion either).  See C++ Standard [cstdarg.syn] paragraph 1 for full details.